# How do I send a POST request to a service from a Java class

Tags: java, json, urlconnection

I need to connect to a remote web service that will issue a JSON response to the request. How to contact the service? I'm thinking of sending a POST request using `HttpurlConnection`. But is there any other ways? more correct?

Comment: JavaScript. But isn't there an `<f:ajax>` tag or something like that?

Comment: @DaveNewton  I'm interested in how to send a post request to a remote web service

Comment: In your JSF backing bean (or put it in a utility class) you can use one of the answers here [Java sending http parameters via post method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Comment: @JGlass thnak you man you save my day!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @elik You should have specified you wanted to do it on the server side.